# Request package raise after signing the offer

Tags: salary, job-offer, new-job, human-resources, negotiation

I received my new job offer and my join date is in next 2 weeks. I signed the offer for a particular package which is $5000 more than my current package. But I just received a 5% salary increment and $5000 bonus in my current job(which now equals to what my new job is offering me).

So my question is, is it good to negotiate the package with my new Employer as my current pay is similar to what my new job is offering me?

Is it ethical? Is there a way for this approach?

Comment: Have you put in your notice for your current job?

Comment: So staying with your current job is no longer an option for you?

Comment: I haven't resigned yet. I am about to

Comment: @tweray no I want to move off.

Answer (score 10):

Why did you want to leave? Only because of the money? If that is the case you could *try* to re-negotiate.

Being on the other end of the table I would likely not want to hire you anymore as it seems I can't trust you on an agreement we struck. In my country I can nullify a contract within the first month without reasons (an employee can leave that way as well, BTW), so I would probably say goodbye there and then...

If there are other reasons you wanted to leave: better long term prospects for instance. Start you new job and earn your better package in the future.

Bottomline: you have signed. Take it or leave it, I guess...

Comment: I am not thinking go off for money. My new career seems more stable and long-term perspective one. Also it's a tech shift for me. So i want to choose that one. My only question is would it be professional to re-negotiate after I signed?

Comment: @Rick not really, no.  It would make you look bad right out of the gate.  Don't do that to yourself.  If you're in on this position for the long haul, having a good relationship with your employer is more important... especially since your old job still isn't offering you any more than your new job is.

Answer (score 2):

If you agreed that number it's difficult that you can get a raise in the offer (you already accepted it).

You can try to play hard and say you won't leave because now the offer is no longer good for you, but you probably lose that opportunity, and you said you want to leave your current job, so i'd take that raise as a little plus to earn before leaving the company and start fresh.

Even if the new company agrees to raise the offer, you won't start in the best way with them.

I'd only take that path if i don't care much about the new company itself and i think i can get a job somewhere else for more money asap.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely.

This is called negotiation.

But you will need to approach it delicately and be prepared for the new company to withdraw their offer.